# How can we use a command with pipe in C#

Tags: c#, windows, command-line

I'm trying to run a command with a pipe that uses findstr.
Following is a simple example of the command. (In actual case my command is more complicated than this, using this command for explanation)

```
 dir | findstr /i /c:"web"
```

following is the function I use to run the process in C#.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/C dir | findstr /i /c:\"web\"",
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
process.Start();

string sResponse = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I haven't figured out how to run this command using this process.
Above will work for commands without | (Pipe)
Please let me know if there are any workarounds.

Comment: i think the complete command after /C needs to be quoted to be read by cmd as one command.

Comment: Presumably `@"/C ""dir | findstr /i /c:""web"" """` but you may have to tweak the quote usage.

Comment: You need to flush the stream every time you write.  You also need a return for dir to start to run.

Comment: Wouldn't that be easier and more efficient to _not_ do this out of process but with .NET built-in functionality?

Comment: @Ralf Your suggestion resolves my problem. Thanks!